# Sync Firefox between OSes like you never leave it

Tags: firefox, sync, operating-systems

I have two OSes: Windows and Linux, both of them install Firefox 29. I would like them to have everything synced like they are two become one. Whenever it opens, it will open exactly to when it closes, disregard which OS I use. Currently, I can get the tabs in other device by go to History > Tab From Other Devices, but I want it to sync tab groups, plugins, passwords, etc. Is it possible? I have read all the guide (hope so) but they don't help.

Comment: I have already done it, but it doesn't work. I know some plugins for syncing, but I prefer to have a native fucntion of Firefox.

Comment: As I have provided already: "Currently, I can get the tabs in other device by go to History > Tab From Other Devices, but I want it to sync tab groups, plugins, passwords, etc."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all your Firefox profiles with their tabs, addons, chached data, etc to sync if you move the folder to a Dropbox like program then symbolic link it.

To do this, move your Windows folder from `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox` to a new folder in Dropbox, say `%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\SymLinks\Firefox`, while Firefox is closed. Then run `mklink \J %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\SymLinks\Firefox %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox` and it will link the folder. Then while in Linux you can remove the `~/.mozilla/Firefox` folder and run `ln -s ~/Dropbox/SymLinks/Firefox ~/.mozilla/` and it will be synced in Linux.

I have been using this method for quite some time now and it's not perfect. Have a backup profile or different browser installed on each system because firefox will start overwriting itself if you open the same profile on different computers. There are a lot of tiny files that get conflicted easily and Dropbox can easily make a gig or more of them if you're not carefull. If you are inexplicably running out of Dropbox space, chek your profile folder for conflict files. Another thing to note is that the Windows and Linux link commands are backwards of each other so make sure you get it right.

Comment: Will this method also work for any program that I need to sync data between Windows and Linux?

Comment: It will. I use it for skype, gimp, game saves, and more.

Comment: Haven't really checked if this method works, but I'll accept it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a native sync feature, you have to create an account, then sign in with both OSs, then you can start syncing. This will work for any devices, including Android, Linux, Mac, Windows, ...

You can access this by pressing the menu button --> Sign in to Sync and after setting it up, it will do the things you wanted. (bookmarks, history, passwords, open tabs and installed add-ons, etc...)

For more information, check out the official support page:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync

Comment: I have done everything like you said: create an account, sign in and sync, set things up. It just only syncs tabs, not tab groups or passwords.

Comment: @Ooker That's weird, try pressing the menu button, then options, and then click the sync tab, make sure the passwords and the other things are checked. Also, it will say sync progression when you press the menu button, maybe its not synced yet. Below the buttons, you will see your email and if you started now, you will see the sync animation.

Comment: I use Firefox 29, it has changed the GUI. It no longer has the orange rectangular menu button on the left. Anyway, I have checked my process and I pretty sure that I follow the support page exactly.

Comment: @Ooker I am not exactly sure what you mean, because I have Firefox 30. By menu, I mean the three lines button on the top right of the window that was added in the new version. http://i.stack.imgur.com/sBYSZ.png is what I mean.

Comment: Wow, I don't know that. But wait, when I go to the Firefox page, it congrats me to have the latest version. And my Firefox is 29.0, Mozilla 5.0. And yes, I do click on the three lines button to sync.

Comment: @Ooker I'm probably on Beta. Why are you refusing to open options --> Sync? This has been there since the ancient days of Firefox, and will probably be never removed.

Comment: No, I don't refuse anything. First I thought that you used the old version because I remembered the Option only existed in the orange button. My bad. However, I do click on the Sync button, it also appears my email.

Comment: @Ooker Here are pictures, this is another way to open it. Hope it's all clear now. http://anony.ws/i/2014/05/20/XDntf.png
http://anony.ws/i/2014/05/20/zSbqE.png

Comment: Yes, that the exactly what I do. Clicking on it will open the Preferences with Sync tab. I have checked every boxes it has. Of course I have my email there already.

Comment: @Ooker If you've already checked all boxes, then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for trying to help me :D

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the profiles.ini file on one of your machines to direct to your Firefox profile on the other. You can find the profiles.ini file in the appdata folder on windows and the .mozilla folder on Linux, they are both hidden by default.

[profile info](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Linux)

Comment: Do you mean that I should copy the profiles.ini in Linux and replace the Windows' one?

Comment: No I wasn't very clear sorry. If you open the profiles.ini file you will find a line telling Firefox where your profile is stored, change that line on one of your machines, it shouldn't matter which, to lead to the folder on the other machine so you open the same profile on both. Downside is that I don't think you can open firefox on both and if you can it may mess with any new bookmarks, history, etc, I don't know for sure.

Comment: On Linux, the path in the profiles.ini is: Path=752b9jwh.default-1398092767752. Do you know where it locates exactly? Google doesn't match anything.

Comment: If you found profiles.ini there should be a "profiles" folder and a folder labeled 752b9jwh.default inside that this is the folder you'll need to direct the firefox on windows to. The best way to get the correct path is to navigate to the folder on windows and Shift + right click copy as path on the folder.

Comment: There is no folder named profiles, only one named 752b9jwh.default-1398092767752 folder next to the profiles.ini. (aha, now I understand the path in the upper comment :P). I guess I know the solution. The question is, if I change the path, what make you think it will make mess of Firefox?

Comment: Its not the path change that would cause problems it would be if you attempted to have that firefox profile open on both computers at once because when firefox is running some files are active so it might be able to open on the other computer because those files are being used and if it does open history and new bookmarks may not save. Note that I don't know for sure if it could possibly be a problem just postulating.

Comment: It works :D. I have accepted your answer. One more thing. If I want to copy the profile to my folder, will it still work? In Windows, when I change the path to `D:\Dropbox/752b9jwh.default...`, Firefox says it cannot load the profile and refuse to open.

Comment: You should be able to move your folder anywhere and it should open as long as you point firefox to the right place. I think you typed the path wrong it should be `D:\Dropbox\752b9jwh.default`. If that doesn't work it could be that dropbox is interfering with things, try closing it and opening firefox.

Comment: You are right, the path should be `D:\Dropbox\75...`. However, the key to make it use the profile outside the folder is change the line `IsRelative=0` to 1. After playing around with this I got this. Thank you so much for helping me.